# Deferred Corrections vs Multigrid

Tags: numerical-methods

I've been looking at the method of Deferred Corrections [(see page 9 of this presentation)](http://www.csm.ornl.gov/workshops/nd2012/documents/talks/jia.pdf) to numerically solve ODE IVPs. To me, the process looks identical to a V-cycle in a multigrid method if the solution was solved directly on each grid. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Might be better placed at the [computational science site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). There are some questions regarding deferred corrections already.

Comment: Oh my God, what a style (of the presentation)!

Comment: I know, I want to use that template on all of my own presentations!  This was the simplest explanation of the original deferred corrections approach I could find.